# Trying to translate NgPickDateTime labels when user change page lang

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular6, ngx-translate

I'm using NgPickDatetime in my Angular app (https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/) and I have a problem when i try to translate labels and messages. 
I follow the instructions in the documentation and It works fine, but the problem is when I change the site language, the labels still in the previous language.

My code is:

**datetime-locale.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule, OwlDateTimeIntl} from 'ng-pick-datetime';
import { DefaultIntl } from './datepicker-locale.component';


@NgModule({
    imports: [OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule],
    providers: [
        {provide: OwlDateTimeIntl, useClass: DefaultIntl},
    ],
})
export class DateTimeLocaleModule {
}
```

**datepicker-locale.component.ts:**

```
import { OwlDateTimeIntl } from 'ng-pick-datetime';

export class DefaultIntl extends OwlDateTimeIntl {
    public cancelBtnLabel = 'Annuleren';
    public setBtnLabel = 'Opslaan';
    private currentLang;

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.getLang();
    }

    public getLang() {
        this.currentLang = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("language"));

        switch (this.currentLang.id) {
            case 'en':
                this.cancelBtnLabel = 'Cancel';
                this.setBtnLabel = 'Set';
                break;
            case 'nl':
                this.cancelBtnLabel = 'Annuleren';
                this.setBtnLabel = 'Opslaan';
                break;
            default:
                this.cancelBtnLabel = 'Annuleren';
                this.setBtnLabel = 'Opslaan';
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

So i'm trying to add ngx-translate to component and reload `getLang()` function when the user change language, but it's doesn't work, because I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for DefaultIntl: (?).
```

The full code of the component with translate service is:

```
import { OwlDateTimeIntl } from 'ng-pick-datetime';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

export class DefaultIntl extends OwlDateTimeIntl {
    public cancelBtnLabel = 'Annuleren';
    public setBtnLabel = 'Opslaan';
    private currentLang;

    constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
        super();

        this.getLang();

        this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe(lang => {
            this.getLang();
        });
    }

    public getLang() {
        this.currentLang = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("language"));

        switch (this.currentLang.id) {
            case 'en':
                this.cancelBtnLabel = 'Cancel';
                this.setBtnLabel = 'Set';
                break;
            case 'nl':
                this.cancelBtnLabel = 'Annuleren';
                this.setBtnLabel = 'Opslaan';
                break;
            default:
                this.cancelBtnLabel = 'Annuleren';
                this.setBtnLabel = 'Opslaan';
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

I need to use translate service, but I can't do in the component. Is there any solution of this problem ?

Thanks!!!

Comment: What  exactly is your problem with the servie. Are you getting any errors on the console?

Comment: Yes, the error is : Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for DefaultIntl: (?).
I think that in the extended class doesn't exist constructor, but how can I inject translate service?

Comment: Did you add it to the `providers` array of this module that you're working on?

Answer (score 6):

I solved adding this:

```
@Inject(TranslateService) private translate
```

into constructor, the full code is:

```
import { OwlDateTimeIntl } from 'ng-pick-datetime';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';

export class DefaultIntl extends OwlDateTimeIntl {
    public cancelBtnLabel = 'Annuleren';
    public setBtnLabel = 'Opslaan';
    private currentLang;

    constructor(@Inject(TranslateService) private translate) {
        super();

        this.getLang();

        this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe(lang => {
            this.getLang();
        });
    }

    public getLang() {
        this.currentLang = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("language"));

        switch (this.currentLang.id) {
            case 'en':
                this.cancelBtnLabel = 'Cancel';
                this.setBtnLabel = 'Set';
                break;
            case 'nl':
                this.cancelBtnLabel = 'Annuleren';
                this.setBtnLabel = 'Opslaan';
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

To set the datepicker labels **Cancel** and **Set** without regionalization:

Create a component and  extend OwlDateTimeIntl :

```
import { OwlDateTimeIntl } from 'ng-pick-datetime';

export class SetPickerLabels extends OwlDateTimeIntl {
public cancelBtnLabel = 'TEXT FOR CANCEL';
public setBtnLabel = 'TEXT FOR SET';
};
```

In the module where you imported **ng-pick-datetime**, import the component, and use as a class for OwlDateTimeIntl provider:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule, OwlDateTimeIntl} from 'ng-pick-datetime';
import { SetPickerLabels } from './set-picker-labels.component';


@NgModule({
imports: [OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule],
providers: [
    {provide: OwlDateTimeIntl, useClass: SetPickerLabels},
],
})
```

**Tested on Angular 6 and Angular 7**

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to import the `TranslateModule` to help your `DateTimeLocaleModule` module understand what `TranslateService` is

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule, OwlDateTimeIntl } from 'ng-pick-datetime';
import { DefaultIntl } from './datepicker-locale.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    OwlDateTimeModule, 
    OwlNativeDateTimeModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: OwlDateTimeIntl,
    useClass: DefaultIntl
  }],
})
export class DateTimeLocaleModule {}
```

I think that Angular wasn't really aware of the `TranslateService` which is exposed as a part of `TranslateModule` and that's why it was giving this error. with this change though, it should work as expected.

Comment: I solved adding this "@Inject(TranslateService) private translate" in constructor and it works correctly!

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

```js
you must put the injection decorator

@Injectable()
export class SetPickerLabels extends OwlDateTimeIntl {
  readonly changes: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
  upSecondLabel = 'Add a second';
  downSecondLabel = 'Minus a second';
  upMinuteLabel = 'Add a minute';
  downMinuteLabel = 'Minus a minute';
  upHourLabel = 'Add a hour';
  downHourLabel = 'Minus a hour';
  prevMonthLabel = 'Previous month';
  nextMonthLabel = 'Next month';
  prevYearLabel = 'Previous year';
  nextYearLabel = 'Next year';
  prevMultiYearLabel = 'Previous 21 years';
  nextMultiYearLabel = 'Next 21 years';
  switchToMonthViewLabel = 'Change to month view';
  switchToMultiYearViewLabel = 'Choose month and year';
  cancelBtnLabel = 'Cancelar';
  setBtnLabel = 'Aceptar';
  rangeFromLabel = 'From';
  rangeToLabel = 'To';
  hour12AMLabel = 'AM';
  hour12PMLabel = 'PM';
}

in the providers:

  providers:[
    { provide: OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS, useValue: MY_CUSTOM_FORMATS },
    { provide: OwlDateTimeIntl, useClass: SetPickerLabels },
  ]
```